# GOOGLE ANALYTICS API UNSAMPLED DATA SAME WAY WITH BIG QUERY

Tags: api, analytics

I was using big query to get unsampled data from Google Analytics... now i want to use the API v4 from Google Analytics... the question is... can i get unsampled data with it in the same way i got it with big query? Thank you in advanced, Cris

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked this documentation --> [Google Analytics v4 Basics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics)

Comment: Yes, checked. The question its about if there is a way to get unsampled data using the API, an alternative way, without dimension limitation and not sampling at all